# Does LINQ know how to optimize "queries"?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, linq

Suppose I do something like

```
 var Ordered = MyList.OrderBy(x => x.prop1).ThenBy(x => x.prop2);
```

Does `MyList.OrderBy(x => x.prop1)` return the filtered list, and then does it further filter that list by `ThenBy(x => x.prop2)`? In other words, is it equivalent to

```
var OrderedByProp1 = MyList.OrderBy(x => x.prop1);
var Ordered = OrderedByProp1.OrderBy(x => x.prop2);
```

???

Because obviously it's possible to optimize this by running a sorting algorithm with a comparator:

```
var Ordered = MyList.Sort( (x,y) => x.prop1 != y.prop1 ? x.prop1 < y.prop1 : ( x.prop2 < y.prop2 ) );
```

If it does do some sort of optimization and intermediate lists are not returned in the process, then how does it know how to do that? How do you write a class that optimizes chains of methods on itself? Makes no sense.

Comment: What flavor of LINQ? LINQ to Objects, LINQ to Entities, etc?

Comment: And if Linq to Entities, which Linq provider? There are many. Note that there are changes in EF7 that make it easier for Linq to Entities providers to better optimize queries.

Comment: If you're connecting to a database use the SQL Profiler to compare the database queries generated in each case and see what the differences are (if any).

Comment: LINQ (to objects) doesn't "optimize" queries but it tries to do the least amount of work possible and in general produces "good enough" results. It's not a silver bullet and for high performance code you may find yourself having to write it all by hand (Roslyn for example does not allow LINQ internally as direct loops are easier to predict true cost). The converse is it can also work entirely fine with high performance code and I use L2O across millions of records in my current system, continuously. Performance is always profile, profile, profile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does `MyList.OrderBy(x => x.prop1)` return the filtered list

No.  LINQ methods (at least typically) return **queries**, not the *results of executing* those queries.

`OrderBy` just returns an object which, when you ask it for an item, will return the first item in the collection given a particular ordering.  But until you actually ask it for a result it's not doing *anything*.

Note you can also get a decent idea as to what's going on by just looking at what `OrderBy` returns.  It returns `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`.  That interface has a method `CreateOrderedEnumerable` which:

> Performs a subsequent ordering on the elements of an IOrderedEnumerable according to a key.

That method is what `ThenBy` uses to indicate that there is a subsequent ordering.

This means that you're building up all of the comparers that you want to be used, from the `OrderBy` and all `ThenBy` calls *before you ever need to generate a single item in the result set*.

For more specifics on *exactly* how you can go about creating this behavior, see [Jon Skeet's blog series on the subject](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/04/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-26a-iorderedenumerable/).

Comment: Even when Jon Skeet doesn't answer a question, he does answer a question.